# Combined style for GeoJSON line in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, line, style

In leaflet I have a GeoJSON of line type. I want the latter to have two styles, the solid color in the background and a dotted line inside, as shown in the following image:

[image]

In the image, I have two GeoJSONs with two different styles. Is it possible to unify that style with a single file?

My code is the following (.js file):

```
var mapCenter = [-33.42, -70.6];

var myMap = L.map('map').setView(mapCenter, 13);


var line_style ={
    "color": '#8d7696',
    "weight":  6,
};

var line_2_style ={
    "color": '#141414',
    "weight":  1,
    "dashArray": "1,5,10"}

L.geoJson(line, {style: line_style}).addTo(myMap);
L.geoJson(line_2, {style: line_2_style}).addTo(myMap);
```

The "line" file is in another folder in Visual Studio Code and has a .js extension.

Comment: Easily achievable in OpenLayers with style array, not possible in Leaflet.

Comment: So the only way is to place a GeoJSOn layer on top of another with different styles, how am I doing now?

Comment: Yes. If you have a lot of such layers, you could create a function that would create the two differently styled layers from the same source/data and create one group layer from them.